# Multiple instances of item in View row

Tags: 7, views, theming

I am getting five instances items in my View row when I wrap image field inside my link field. This is what I have in the template file:

```
    <?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
    <?php print $field->separator; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
    <?php print $field->label_html; ?>
    <?php //print $field->content; ?>
    <div class="myRow">
        <div class="myImg">
            <span class="featuredVideo"></span>
            <a href="<?php print $fields['field_news_link']->content; ?>" target="_blank"><?php print $fields['field_news_image']->content; ?></a>
            <?php //print $fields['field_news_image']->content; ?>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php print $fields['field_news_link']->content; ?>"><?php print $fields['field_news_source']->content; ?></a>
    </div>
  <?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If I uncomment `<?php //print $field->content; ?>` and remove the linked image and the rest of my mark up, I don't get multiple instances of the item.

Comment: Try using `$field` and not `$fields` for the output.

Comment: It breaks the page. I get these errors: 
Notice: Undefined variable: field in include() (line 31 of /templates/views-view-fields--featured-news--block-1.tpl.php).
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in include() (line 31 of /templates/views-view-fields--featured-news--block-1.tpl.php).

Comment: You can actually output the fields as you do, but in that case you should remove/comment out the `foreach ...` and `endforeach` rows. See [views-view-fields.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php/7)

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Pretty obvious fix that I missed. If you provide this as an answer I'd be happy to approve it. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could be of help. I've added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field template prints all the fields as a row. If you want to output the row of fields manually you need to remove the `foreach` iteration of the fields.

See [views-view-fields.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php/7) for more info.